# im trying to change the position and size of the carousel with scss but it seems to do nothing

Tags: sass, bootstrapper

here is the component i want to change i even added an extra div around to move it but i am finding no solution with scss

here is the scss i am using

```
.carousel{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.carousel-item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;}

<div class="carouselbox">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100 code " src="img/developing_redesigned.PNG" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/developing_redesigned.PNG" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100 " src="img/developing_redesigned.PNG" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Uhhhhh, could you maybe add the scss code you already have?

Comment: i added what i already have

Comment: So you want to move it down the page? And the ```margin-top``` does not get applied?

Comment: all the code i try to apply does not work but yeah i am trying to do that